# Unable to login to stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, stackexchange.com, network-profile

So strange.
I am using a few SE network sites, all with the same login details, and the accounts are connected.
When I come into SE and try to login, it does not find my credencials, and offers I make a new OpenID.

What is even more strange is when I came into meta right now to post this - my profile was loaded.

**EDIT**    more details as per request:

first visit to StackExchange.com looks fresh [doesnt take my login from network]
[image: first visit]

i click google which is how i do on the whole network
[image: choose login path]

..go to google, provide creds...
redirected back to SE to see :
[image: redirect return]

bummer. 
Not confirming - i click the META link on the top instead and come to this:
[image: meta logged in]

**EDIT 2**

Trying again and creating a new openID i get
[image: Go find a panda.]

BUT noted is that i am now logged in - what is going on?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you're seeing when you visit stackexchange.com? Screenshots would also help. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear Edited with screenshot.

Comment: And if you click the "Confirm and Create" button, what happens? No worry, Adam is a dev and can fix any possible issue it might cause.

Comment: 2 things happen. First i am told to go look for a panda. Second, i found my profile. it appears to be unconnected. screenshots added.

Comment: @AdamLear anything you can note as an answer to what went wrong? [this isnt the first time im having profile issues..]

Comment: @AdamLear, any progress on this? I have the exact same issue and I don't want to create an unconnected separate profile like "a deer" did.

Comment: note, I did click through, and I did **NOT** get an unconnected profile like "a deer" did.  (the accepted answer works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of the next person who finds this... You want to click "Confirm and Create New Account" in step #3. Yes, it's confusing and misleading, but generally it will *not* create a new account - it'll just create a new *profile* for you on the stackexchange.com site, which'll be properly linked to your existing profiles on other sites. If this does not happen, and a new account gets created, please contact us and request that your site account be associated with that network profile.

The login system on *most* other sites has been updated such that it'll normally recognize you before it gets to this point, which reduces confusion considerably. At some point, we'll probably do the same for stackexchange.com and this'll stop being weird.

Comment: Sorry, I'm back, and this time it is http://data.stackexchange.com that I can't SE-login to, and this time, it **did** create a garbage account that isn't hooked to my real one: http://data.stackexchange.com/users/27091/nathan-harvey

Comment: Yeah, data.se is... weird and different, @NH. If you end up in this situation there, contact support & we'll try & get you sorted out.

Comment: I tried that and got this error page after clicking Submit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/contact/submit

Comment: Hmm... Wouldn't have expected it to blow up like that. Just select "Other" and put the info in the freeform text field, @NH.