# Why am I being redirected to meta when I want to log in at stackexchange.com

Tags: support, login, stackexchange.com

Since today, when I go to stackexchange.com and click the login button, I am being redirected to the login at meta.stackexchange.com.

When I login there, I am again being redirected to the main stackexchange.com site.
This is new, why was it added?

Comment: This [used to cause bugs in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269375/unable-to-login-to-stackexchange-com), linking to MSE kind of solve those bugs.